# Loading values from properties file into jsp without using scriplets inside JSP page

Tags: java, spring, jsp, servlets, web

I need to read value from property and this value is to be displayed on my JSP page.
I performed this by adding java code inside the JSP page as shown below :

```
<%@page import="java.io.InputStream" %>
<%@page import="java.util.Properties" %>

<%
    InputStream stream = application.getResourceAsStream("etc/appconfigweb.properties");
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.load(stream);
    String env = props.getString("environment");
%>
    <% env %>
```

Now I would like to load properties file value into JSP page without putting java code inside the JSP. Is there a method to load value into JSP.

Comment: Why not set the value as an attribute from the servlet and then access it using the bracket notation in the JSP - e.g. ${env}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use jstl tag library to load property on your jsp page and please ensure your property files location should be `WEB-INF\classes\etc\`

```
<%@ taglib uri = "http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix = "c" %>
<%@ taglib uri = "http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" prefix = "fmt" %>
....
....
  <fmt:setLocale value = "en"/>
  <fmt:setBundle basename = "etc.appconfigweb" var = "lang"/>
  <fmt:message key = "environment" bundle = "${lang}"/>
```

[Example of jstl for reading Property file](https://websphereportaltechies.wordpress.com/2013/11/26/reading-properties-file-in-jsp-using-jstl-taglib/)

Comment: My project would require me to put the property file outside classpath. Is it possible to load the values from outside class path into jsp using above method.

Comment: ???environment???  is  showing beacause of else your property file not exits,please clean your project and built it. and run again . i thing it should be work.

Comment: K am sorry for my mistake. I'll try again.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using JSTL and the < fmt:bundle > tag like this:

```
<%@ taglib uri = "http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix = "c" %>
<%@ taglib uri = "http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" prefix = "fmt" %>
....
....
<fmt:bundle basename = "etc.appconfigweb">
     <fmt:message key = "environment"/><br/>
</fmt:bundle>
```

For more information see this [JSTL example](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jstl_format_bundle_tag.htm)

Comment: When I tried this I am getting output as ???environment??? not the value of environment.

Comment: sorry for this, check my updated answer. Basically remove the .properties from the basename and the folder delimiter must be (.)

Comment: do you have something like "environment=something" in a folder/file "etc/appcoinfigweb.properties" in your app? As I do it on my machine it works as it should...

Comment: Yes I have appconfigweb.properties inside etc. Yet I get the same error.

Comment: can you ensure your property file location? , it should be in web-inf/classess

Comment: It's not inside web-inf/classes. Its relative path is : src/main/etc/appconfigweb.properties. In my project I would have to put the property file outside the class structure what can be done about that.

Comment: when you build your application it is converted into a war file. The java code is located under WEB-INF/classes. To be able to read the file using the fmt tag the properties file must be in that directory